# HTML Button not clickable in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a button with the text "Description" that in IE is not clickable. Well, actually the far right edge of it is clickable, but not the whole button and text content of the button. It works fine in modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox), but not in IE. I am using IE 11 for testing. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

I've tried to strip out as much as possible...

```css
.vertical-button {
  width: 1px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: -68px;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: 0.8s;
  -ms-transition: 0.8s;
  -o-transition: 0.8s;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.vertical-button {
  right: -100px;
}

.project--active .vertical-button {
  opacity: 1;
}

.project__image,
.project__text {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 408px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.project__text {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.project__image,
.project__text {
  width: 280px;
  height: 210px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.project__text {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.project {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  padding: 18px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 614px;
  height: 246px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.project {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 740px;
  height: 295px;
}

.l-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 86%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.l-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
}

.l-clear::after,
.l-wrapper::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.l-section {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.l-section__bg {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

.l-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 99;
}

.vertical-button__btn,
.vertical-button__btn:focus,
.vertical-button__btn:active {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  display: inline;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  outline-offset: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-32%);
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.vertical-button__stroke {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div data-reactroot="">
    <div class="l-container">
      <div class="l-section l-section__bg">
        <div class="l-wrapper">
          <div class="project project--active">
            <div class="project__image"></div>
            <div class="project__text">
              <h3 class="project__heading">Title</h3>
              <div class="vertical-button">
                <button class="vertical-button__btn">Description</button>
                <div class="vertical-button__stroke"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

I have found that if I remove this piece of HTML the button becomes clickable...

```
<div class="project__image"></div>
```

But this still doesn't help me understand why it's happening or how to fix it! I cannot actually remove that div in the real project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE to test, but I can tell you some ideas from my experience.

**1. Check if another element is overlapping your button.**

Being IE, it may handle CSS differently, hence overlapping. Since removing that image class div resolves the problem, I'd guess this would be the cause of the problem.

**2. Validate the HTML.**

Forgetting to close tags can create very, very bizarre bugs, also difficult to find.

**3. Try turning that button into an anchor `<a>`**

There could be browsers who won't handle the click event properly.

**4. Stop using IE :)**

At least use Edge.

Comment: 1. I have extensively checked for CSS overlapping... I'm scratching my head here. 2. Validated and passed. 3. Also tried, same behavior. 4. I couldn't agree more! But I am testing for users - not that I would ever touch that nightmare browser myself as one.

Comment: Try to change values in the class `project_image` and see if it fixes anything.

Comment: Also tried to no effect... The only values are `position:relative; width: 280px; height: 210px; display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto;` As you can see in your browser even without IE.

Comment: In my browser it works fine, so I can't reproduce the problem. Try to give a new fresh class to that problematic `div` and add properties from inspect, while testing the clicking.

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Comment: Try to put that `div` in another position in the html, say after the button.

Comment: If it solves, then you can arrange the divs position with css.